# When does a street view become available

Tags: google-street-view

After uploading several different street views for a business, I have tried to embed them using the API. Every time I do via the location I get the error that the street view is unavailable. Is there a waiting time from when the street view is available to embed?

Comment: http://www.efmarburger.com/newsletter/test.html

Comment: Now its showing only the Google street view, not the photo spheres I uploaded

Comment: Now it shows the google Street view, and not the custom sphere that I created.